# How does this for loop work and end?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

There are two initialisation and no "`x<y`" to limit the iterations. So how does this loop work?

```js
var features = [{
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91721, 151.22630),
  type: 'info'
}, {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91539, 151.22820),
  type: 'info'
}, {
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91747, 151.22912),
  type: 'info'
}];
for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
  addMarker(feature);
}
```

Comment: `feature` will always equal `features[i]`, and `i++` still increments. This should still loop over 3 times.

Comment: Like any other `for` loop, `for(initialization; condition; final-expression)`

Comment: When `i=3` features[i] will return `undefined` and that will break the loop

Comment: Plenty of people with good answers here, but going forward a less confusing construct is of course. `features.forEach(addMarker)` , Of course you wanted to know why it worked, but for people browsing might be worth pointing out the forEach.

Comment: @Keith You are right that mentioning `forEach` or any other method would be out of scope. But for anyone who is looking for it, please refer [Different ways to loop through array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Access to an out-of-bound index in Javascript will yield `undefined`, which is a falsey value. Once the index has got outside of the bound, the `feature = features[i]` assignment, which evaluates to the value it assigns, will be considered `false` and the loop will exit.

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have imagined that it could matter ! I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut where if you wish to assign and return same value, you can do `return variable = value`. This will return `value`

**Sample**

```js
var x;
function notify(v){
  return x = v;
}

console.log(notify(10))
```

So in your code, when you do `feature = features[3]`, since `features[3]` is undefined, it returns `undefined` which is falsey. Hence your loop breaks.

**Sample**

```js
var x = 0;
if(x = 1){
  console.log('Success')
}
else{
  console.log('Error')
}

if(x = undefined){
  console.log('Success')
}
else{
  console.log('Error')
}
```

**Note** you loop will break if `features[i]` return `0` or `false` or `undefined` or any other falsey value. This is working fine in this case, but I would not recommend it.